# Linker script, init C variables

Tags: c, gcc, assembly, linker-scripts

I try find answer long time. Sorry but I really can't find it.

I use gcc,ld,gcc(for assembler compilation).

I wrote ld script:

```
SECTIONS
{
  .text : *{.text}
}
LS_size = (SIZEOF(.text) + 2048 ) & ( 0xF800 ) >> 9 ;
```

I try use LS_size from assembler:

```
_rom_size:
.byte LS_size
```

Its work fine, but on C code I can't set value to variable:

```
struct my_struct vari = {
  .codesize = LS_size,
}
```

If I extern LS_size, I got:

```
error: initializer element is not constant
```

How can I set default value for my constant C variables from variables, which are produced in ld scripts?

Comment: `LS_size` isn't known at compile time, since it's a linker script variable. You could try adding an `extern const size_t LS_size;` declaration in your C code, and move the initialization of `vari.codesize` to some function.

Comment: Then I compile the asm(.S) source I got: 0x00, (it is a _rom_size). But then I link it i got: 0x04. This means that I can specify which object file what data need to write to link stage. But I don't know how I can to write this on C code.

Comment: Well, I might be wrong, but I when you initialize the struct while declaring it I think the RHS must be a compile-time constant. Hence the suggestion to move the initialization in my previous comment.

Comment: If this is true, then it is very bad.

Answer (score 1):

Write in C:

```
struct my_st { 
    long the_code_sz;
};

struct my_st vv = {
  .the_code_sz = ((long)(&LS_size))
};
```

Then you can use

```
vv.the_code_sz
```

LS_size is a symbol and the address of that symbol is the value you gave it in the linker script.

Answer (score 0):

Also remember that linkerskript variables are not datatypes. They represent adresses- and what is stored there is completely arbitrary

Its bascially what you get with &VariableName in C.